# Is there a way to restrict reactions to user updated elements?

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

In my RStudio shiny app I have observers that update selectInputs. Is there a way to avoid a cascade of reactions? If the user changes input1 I want it to update input2. But I don't want this to trigger an update to input3 which is what happens below.

For example, it would be ideal if I could put the equivalent of an `isolate` around and update as in:

`isolate(updateSelectInput())`

so that it makes the initial update but does not trigger any other changes.

Is this possible?

```
server<-function(session, input, output) {


  observeEvent(input$input1, {
    updateSelectInput(session, "input2", selected="3")

  })


  observeEvent(input$input2, {
    updateNumericInput(session, "input3",value=round(rnorm(1),2))
    # resetting input 2
    updateSelectInput(session, "input2", selected="1")
  })


}

ui<-fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for the number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("input1", label="Input1", choices=c("a", "b", "c"), selected="a"),
        selectInput("input2", label="Input2", choices=c("1", "2", "3"), selected="1"),
        numericInput("input3", label="Input3", value=3)
    ),

    mainPanel(

    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: you app doesnt make sense to me, you're updating `input1` hence it updates `input2` therefore `input3` gets updated too. now if you update `input2` then `input3` gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

I sort of agree with Pork Chop that you'd probably be better of rethinking the design of this and trigger the update in some other way (but I guess you know your app best). There's an easy and ugly way to fix this and still have the same observers:

```
server<-function(session, input, output) {
  run.once <<- FALSE

  observeEvent(input$input1, {
    run.once <<- TRUE
    updateSelectInput(session, "input2", selected="3")
  })


  observeEvent(input$input2, {
    if (run.once==TRUE){
      run.once <<- FALSE
      return(NULL) 
    } 
    updateNumericInput(session, "input3",value=round(rnorm(1),2))
    # resetting input 2
    updateSelectInput(session, "input2", selected="1")
  })


}

ui<-fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for the number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("input1", label="Input1", choices=c("a", "b", "c"), selected="a"),
      selectInput("input2", label="Input2", choices=c("1", "2", "3"), selected="1"),
      numericInput("input3", label="Input3", value=3)
    ),

    mainPanel(

    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

**Edit 1**
A bit more generic solution, still pretty ugly though.

```
server<-function(session, input, output) {
  triggerd.by <<- NULL

  observeEvent(input$input1, {
    if (is.null(triggerd.by)) triggerd.by <<- "input1"
    if (triggerd.by != "input1") return(NULL)
    updateSelectInput(session, "input2", selected="3")
    reactiveTimer(10,{triggerd.by<<-NULL})
  })


  observeEvent(input$input2, {
    print(triggerd.by)
    if (is.null(triggerd.by)) triggerd.by <<- "input2"
    if (triggerd.by != "input2") return(NULL)
    updateNumericInput(session, "input3",value=round(rnorm(1),2))
    updateSelectInput(session, "input2", selected="1")
    print(triggerd.by)
    reactiveTimer(10,{triggerd.by<<-NULL})
  })

}

ui<-fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for the number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("input1", label="Input1", choices=c("a", "b", "c"), selected="a"),
      selectInput("input2", label="Input2", choices=c("1", "2", "3"), selected="1"),
      numericInput("input3", label="Input3", value=3)
    ),

    mainPanel(

    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the response. Agreed that this example is extremely clunky but you both see the issue. What you're suggesting may work but in a real world setting you'd have many observers and it would be quite the hassle to have many "run.once" equivalents. This is actually exactly the situation I have in the full app where I have a global list of initial settings. Perhaps there is no way around this?

Comment: I see your problem, i don't think there's a good way around this except for maybe blocking the event to propagate from Javascript (bind function to shiny and block events for n milliseconds after change). I updated my answer which is done all in R, the solution is more generic but it's still really ugly though.